# Error: java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:sqlserver

Tags: java, sql-server, wowza

I have a wowza server (built with Java) and need it to save logs to a SQL Server 2005 Database. I downloaded the **sqljdbc4.jar** jar file from Microsoft and placed it in **C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\lib\ext**. I also added the classpath to a windows variable, but am getting this error:

**java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:sqlserver**

These are the wowza configuration settings for SQL server:

```
log4j.appender.SQ=org.apache.log4j.jdbc.JDBCAppender
log4j.appender.SQ.Driver=com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver
log4j.appender.SQ.URL=jdbc:sqlserver:\\Myserver;databaseName=WowzaLog
log4j.appender.SQ.user=sa
log4j.appender.SQ.password=123
log4j.appender.SQ.layout=com.wowza.wms.logging.ECLFPatternLayout
log4j.appender.SQ.layout.OutputHeader=false
log4j.appender.SQ.sql=my insert SQL
```

It's not a wowza problem. It's something related to JAVA but I'm not a Java expert.

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5616898/java-sql-sqlexception-no-suitable-driver-found-for-jdbcmicrosoftsqlserver

Comment: The slashes in your JDBC url are pointing the wrong way.

Answer (score 0):

Does Wowza have any lib folder? This would typically have lots of jar files in it that wowza would need to use.

Normally you put the JDBC driver jar file in there not in the Java runtime ext environment.

Also the Database path seems wrong. It needs to have forward slashes not backslashes. It needs to be like this:

jdbc:sqlserver://server:port;DatabaseName=dbname

Comment: yes it has lib folder and I copped my jar into it already, but I still have the same error