# Connection applet <-> database via browser

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, applet, database-connection

I have problem with my applet.It works fine in applet viewer but in the `Web browser` it throws an Exception.

Exception details:

```
`SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:mysql://s46.eatj.com:3307/cmentarz
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-2" java.lang.NullPointerException
at JDBC.LogIn(JDBC.java:49)
at AdminPanelLogIn$1.actionPerformed(AdminPanelLogIn.java:64)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)`
```

I already have signed my jar file using JARmaker.

My `getConnection` method code:

```
public Connection getConnection() throws SQLException {

    try {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    } catch (java.lang.ClassNotFoundException e) {
        System.err.print("ClassNotFoundException: ");
        System.err.println(e.getMessage());
    }

    try {
        con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, userid, password);
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        System.err.println("SQLException: " + ex.getMessage());
    }
    return con;
}
```

`Userid`,`password` and `url` are correct because it works in applet viewer.

`static String url = "jdbc:mysql://s46.eatj.com:3307/cmentarz";`

So, what could be the problem?

Comment: Possible duplicate :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5616898/java-sql-sqlexception-no-suitable-driver-found-for-jdbcmicrosoftsqlserver

Comment: As an aside.  An applet should not have direct access to the DB.  Instead force it to work through a server that mediates access & limits what it can do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure that the `MySQL` jar is available to your applet when running in a browser. You can specify this in your `applet` (or `object`) tag:

```
<applet code="org.package.MyApplet" width="800" height="600" archive="myappletjar.jar,mysql-connector-java-5.1.6-bin.jar">
</applet>
```

Also make sure that the jar file exists in the same location as your applet jar file so that it is available for download.