# Jmeter - No suitable driver found for jdbc:microsoft:sqlserver://x.x.x.x:1433

Tags: sql-server, jdbc, jmeter

I'm using Jmeter 2.9 and trying to connect to SQL Server 2008.
Within `JDBC Connection Configuration` and have the following in my connection properties:

```
Database URL = jdbc:microsoft:sqlserver://x.x.x.x:1433
JDBC Driver Class = com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver
```

I've downloaded the latest `Microsoft SQL Server JDBC Drivers` and placed the following jars under jmeter/lib directory: `sqljdbc.jar`, `sqljdbc4.jar`.

I'm getting the following error:

> java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:microsoft:sqlserver://x.x.x.x:1433

Can you please suggest what I'm missing?

Comment: Have you already checked discussions displayed in `Related` list for your question? There is already a lot of similar questions with solutions. E.g. [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5616898/java-sql-sqlexception-no-suitable-driver-found-for-jdbcmicrosoftsqlserver).

Comment: Thanks for the link Alies. That helped me narrow down the issue. The Database URL was wrong. It needed to be jdbc:microsoft:sqlserver://x.x.x.x:1433;Database=SchemaName. Also I needed only one jar file under jmeter/lib - that was sqljdbc4.jar.

Answer (score 14):

your solution does not work for me, here is my solution:

​Adding jdbc connection Library into Jmeter lib folder:

1. Download the lastest jdbc driver from Microsoft

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/sqlserver/aa937724.aspx

2. Unzip the file and find which driver you need:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms378422.aspx

3. Copy the required JAR file into jmeter/lib folder. (you need to restart the jmeter if you are running it.)
4. in my JDBC Configuration:

   ```
    DatabaseURL: jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:port;DatabaseName=mydb;

    JDBC Driver Class: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver

    User Name: (SQL server access user name)

    Password: (user's password)
   ```
5. Give a Variable name for the config: e.g. JDBC_Connection
6. When you create a JDBC request, use this name in "Variable Name Bound to Pool" field.

Answer (score 2):

The only thing I can add to Vin.X's answer is that you can specify the location of your sqljdbc4.jar as a property of your test plan, by browsing for it where it says **Add directory or jar to classpath**

This is useful if you want to keep libs like this separate from your jMeter distribution folder, to make it easier to update jMeter for example.

Answer (score 2):

First download JDBC jar files from below link i have shared:

http://tinyurl.com/o5hgpmt

Extract all *.jar files to:  C:\apache-jmeter-2.11\lib

then start JMeter

and in your JDBC Connection Configuration element write below connections as per your database:

Database URL: jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://x.x.x.x:1433;DatabaseName=yourdatabase;

JDBC Driver class: net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver

Username: give username of the sql server database
Password: give password of the sql server database

My connection is successful..
Hope this helps every body..

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  Would it be possible to put a link to the original source website of the drivers for posterity (so that if someone happens across this answer in a few years ( :) ) and the link is dead they stand a chance of getting the stuff?)

Comment: @GHC don't worry mate the link is made from my personnel Google drive sharing, i think it will be safe..

but since you want links you can download jar files from http://sourceforge.net/projects/jtds/files/

and rest sqljdbc.jar and sqljdbc4.jar can be downloaded from Microsoft website for free