# unable to connect to Database from my java code

Tags: java, sql-server, jdbc, exception, database-connection

i keep on getting the following error when ever i try to run my code to check connection between `java` code and db.

```
    java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:sqlserver://192.168.1.100
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at StoredProcedure.main(StoredProcedure.java:19)
```

Comment: What database are you using? What JDBC driver are you using?

Comment: Check jdbc driver for Sql Server. It is missing.

Comment: mssql and jdbc driver is sqljdbc4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's not really enough information here to help you. Check out [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5616898/java-sql-sqlexception-no-suitable-driver-found-for-jdbcmicrosoftsqlserver) for a good example on how to pose your question, and possibly find an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Its' showing `No suitable driver found`. Check your `jdk` compatible driver version with `sql server`.

[Check system requirements here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms378422(v=sql.110).aspx)

[Both jdk 7 and jdk 8 compatible jar file](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/sqlserver/aa937724.aspx)