# SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc in Java

Tags: java, jdbc

I found many answers to similar questions but I still can't solve my problem.

My connection code is:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.text.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.sql.*;

public class TransformData
{
public static void main(String args[])
{
    String url = "jdbc:sqlserver://SQLFULL:1433;databaseName=BA_ELTRUN;";
    Connection dbcon;
    Statement stmt;
    ResultSet rs;
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    try
    {
        Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
    }
    catch(java.lang.ClassNotFoundException e)
    {
        System.out.print("ClassNotFoundException: ");
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }

    try
    {
        dbcon = DriverManager.getConnection(url,"username","password");
        stmt = dbcon.createStatement();
    }
     catch(SQLException e)
     {
         System.out.print("SQLException: ");
         System.out.println(e.getMessage());
     }
}
}
```

When I run this I get the following exception:

```
ClassNotFoundException: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:sqlserver://Konstantina\SQLFULL; databaseName=BA_ELTRUN
```

sqljdbc.jar and sqljdbca.jar are on this directory:C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server JDBC Driver 2.0\Sqljdbc_2.0\Enu
Do I have to move them in another directory?

Comment: if you import `com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver` does your app compile without errors?

Comment: @MateusViccari Do you mean in an import statement like this `import com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver;` ? Sorry if this is a stupid question, I am new to all this stuff

Comment: Yeah, or just replace `Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");` by `Class.forName(com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver.class.getName());`. If by doing this your IDE shows an error in that line, that's because the library was not correctly added to the project.

Comment: @MateusViccari There is an error message: `error: package com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc does not exist import com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver;`

Comment: That's it, the lib was not added. What build system are you using? (Maven, ANT) or what IDE are you using?

Comment: @MateusViccari I use Textpad

Comment: Possible duplicate of [java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:microsoft:sqlserver](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5616898/java-sql-sqlexception-no-suitable-driver-found-for-jdbcmicrosoftsqlserver)

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `SQLServerDriver` library to the project dependencies

Comment: I never used TextPad, but you should have a way to package your application into a .jar file, which would create the manifest.mf file pointing to the libraries. Usually this is easier if you use some IDE, like Netbeans, Eclipse or Intellij rather than a simple text editor

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that when you register the driver via the Class.forName call, it is expected to already be on the classpath. The ClassNotFoundException you are receiving means that the sqljdbc.jar and sqljdbca.jar libraries are not on your classpath so you will need to ensure they are included. See the following for additional details and exact steps to ensure the libraries are on your classpath:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms378526(v=sql.110).aspx

Comment: I add them into these direcories: C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\lib\ext and C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_79\jre\lib\ext and finally it works