# No suitable driver found for jdbc:sqlserver://x.x.x.x

Tags: java, sql-server, jakarta-ee, jdbc

I'm trying to expose this function as web service,my function show all the databases in a host and i got this error,i'm trying to connect to microsoft sql server.
Any idea where i'am wrong.

```
public List<String> connexion(){
             Connection conn = null;
            List <String> listdb= new ArrayList<>();
            listdb.add("ok");
        try {

             String dbURL = "jdbc:sqlserver://x.x.x.x\\sqlexpress";
             String user = "xxx";
             String pass = "xxx";
             conn = DriverManager.getConnection(dbURL, user, pass);
             if (conn != null) {
                 DatabaseMetaData dm = (DatabaseMetaData) conn.getMetaData();
                 System.out.println("Driver name: " + dm.getDriverName());
                 System.out.println("Driver version: " + dm.getDriverVersion());
                 System.out.println("Product name: " + dm.getDatabaseProductName());
                 System.out.println("Product version: " + dm.getDatabaseProductVersion());
                 ResultSet rs = conn.getMetaData().getCatalogs();

                 while (rs.next()) {
                     listdb.add(rs.getString("TABLE_CAT"));
                     System.out.println("TABLE_CAT = " + rs.getString("TABLE_CAT") );
                     return listdb;

                 }
                 return listdb;
             }

         } catch (SQLException ex) {
             ex.printStackTrace();
         } 
        finally {
             try {
                 if (conn != null && !conn.isClosed()) {
                     conn.close();
                 }
             } catch (SQLException ex) {
                 ex.printStackTrace();
             }

    }
        return listdb;

    }
```

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5616898/java-sql-sqlexception-no-suitable-driver-found-for-jdbcmicrosoftsqlserver?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: Did you include JAR file for database connection in your libraries?

Comment: yes jar file included

Comment: which jar you have included?and have you included the port and DB name in the URL?

Comment: no need to port,the connexion worked in a main class,but now i want to run my services on server

Comment: Maybe post the exact stack trace here. It is a missing jar file on the server.  Also which server? JBoss requires you to deploy the drivers jar before deployment. Just because it runs on your PC does not mean it will run on your server.

Comment: I'm running my program on wildfly 9.x server