# Add classpath to Eclipse run configuration

Tags: java, eclipse, jdbc

I have JDBC driver connected to my Eclipse project. According to MS [manual](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/jdbc/using-the-jdbc-driver?view=sql-server-2017) I need to set claspath for JDBC. How to do this in Eclipse? I suppose it should be somewhere in run configuration, but I can't find it. Where I can set classpath in Eclipse?

I need to set CLASSPATH environment variable and not just add jar file. I can connect to SQL server from my project while LOG4J library can't. I suppose since it loads driver at runtime.

Comment: I don't need to set jar files location, I need to set CLASSPATH run time environment variable

Comment: you add jars to the classpath. In your case it would be JDBC's jar. PS- Use build tool like maven/gradle.

Comment: I'm using maven and log4j and JDBC driver are added. Projects compiles, but run complains `log4j:ERROR Failed to excute sql
java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for "jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;databaseName=ERP_IDMS"`

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5616898/java-sql-sqlexception-no-suitable-driver-found-for-jdbcmicrosoftsqlserver

Comment: @Shanu Gupta this is not the same issue. I can connect to SQL server from my project while LOG4J library can't. I suppose since it loads driver at runtime

Comment: Oh alright. You might want to include these details in the question.

Comment: Forget about the `CLASSPATH` environment variable, most ways of executing Java programs don't use it, and relying on it will only make for brittle programs

Comment: it's no me, it log4j needs `CLASSPATH`

Answer (score 1):

**Project** menu -> **Properties** -> **Java Build Path**

You can add .jar files to your classpath in the **Libraries** tab