# Unable To Connect To MS SQL Server Using JAVA

Tags: java, sql-server

This is my code to connect to MS SQL Server from JAVA.. It is producing the error : java.sql.SQLException: **No suitable driver found for**.

**The driver I have downloaded from Microsoft's site.**

mssql-jdbc-7.4.1.jre12.jar
mssql-jdbc-7.4.1.jre12-shaded.jar

**Few details :**

Server Name : DESKTOP-2LFJRMD
DB / Instance Name : Test_Learning

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DatabaseMetaData;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;

public class MakeConnectionToSQL {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String varConnectionString;
        Connection varConnection;
        String varUser;
        String varPass;
        varConnectionString = " jdbc:sqlserver: " + 
        " //DESKTOP-2LFJRMD\\ " +
        " databaseName=Test_Learning";
        varUser = "sa";
        varPass = "Mukesh@1507";
        try
        {
            varConnection = DriverManager.getConnection
            (
            varConnectionString, 
            varUser, 
            varPass
            );
            System.out.println("Yesss, Connected");
        }
        catch(SQLException e)
        {
            System.out.println("Oh No, Connection Failed");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:microsoft:sqlserver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5616898/java-sql-sqlexception-no-suitable-driver-found-for-jdbcmicrosoftsqlserver)

Comment: Did you add it properly to the classpath?

Answer (score 0):

Register jdbc driver for SQL Server using :

```java
   DriverManager.registerDriver(new com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver());
```

or

```java
   Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
```

Comment: Hello All..

I got connection working, but somehow.. the error messages are pretty strange, seeing the log.. it does not mention anything about the version of JRE.. - and that is where the problem was lying..

i had downloaded SQL driver for 12 and was using JRE 8.. and so, the connection was not working..

the moment i changed the JRE path from 8-12, it all started working..

strange. - but, thanks all.

Thanks,
Mukesh L.