# Fix 'No suitable driver found for jdbc' error in Java db connection to sqlserver

Tags: java, sql-server

I tried to create a connection between java and SQL Server.
The driver is working, but 'Driver Class' that I wrote in the code raise this error:

> 'No suitable driver found for jdbc:sqlserver://DESKTOP-04\SQL:1433;databaseName=Onschedule'

[image: snapshot of my code and the error I've got]

Comment: You need to post code as text not an image.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:microsoft:sqlserver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5616898/java-sql-sqlexception-no-suitable-driver-found-for-jdbcmicrosoftsqlserver)

Answer (score -1):

Your embedded database does not have access to a `.jar`. You need to make sure that the `Drivers` node has access to the `JavaDB` `.jar` file. This file is typically located in the `bin/` folder in the directory that `JavaDB` was installed on your machine.