# SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:sqlserve:z/localhost:1433;databaseName=isTaskDB;user=is;password=1234

Tags: java, sql, sql-server, jdbc

I've found this question before but none of the answers work for me!

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException {

        Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
        String 
        connectionURL="jdbc:sqlserve:z/localhost:1433;databaseName=isTaskDB;user=is;password=1234";
        Connection con =DriverManager.getConnection(connectionURL);
        System.out.println("done");
}
```

I get this error:

> Exception in thread "main" java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver
>   found for
>   jdbc:sqlserve:z/localhost:1433;databaseName=isTaskDB;user=is;password=1234
>     at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:689)     at
>   java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:270)  at
>   is_prog_task.Is_prog_task.main(Is_prog_task.java:26) Java Result: 1

why??

Comment: Have you added a jar with the MS Sql Server Driver to your classpath? If not, you can get more information here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/jdbc/microsoft-jdbc-driver-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: Also - the connection url reads "...jdbc:sqlserve:z?..." perhaps tha tshould be "...jdbc:sqlserver:z?..."

Comment: Does this answer your question? [java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:microsoft:sqlserver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5616898/java-sql-sqlexception-no-suitable-driver-found-for-jdbcmicrosoftsqlserver)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try replacing

`jdbc:sqlserve:z/localhost:1433;databaseName=isTaskDB;user=is;password=1234`

with

`jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;databaseName=isTaskDB;user=is;password=1234`

See MS SQL Server [Programming Guide for JDBC SQL Driver](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/jdbc/building-the-connection-url) for more information.

Comment: Thanks, that's right!